# 2D Collision detection in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, collision-detection

This is my first time writing a small winform game. When researching into collision detection i know that i need to set my bounds first.

```
    Me.Controls.Add(PlayerShip) 'imports the picture box onto the PlayScreen
    PlayerShip.Width = 40
    PlayerShip.Height = 40 'Dimensions of the player ship
    PlayerShip.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle 'adds a border to the picturebox
    PlayerShip.BackColor = Color.White 'adds colour to the ship background
    PlayerShip.SetBounds(x:=40, y:=40, height:=40, width:=40)
```

And then the other picture box

```
    Me.Controls.Add(WallNorth)
    WallNorth.Width = 750
    WallNorth.Height = 5
    WallNorth.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    WallNorth.BackColor = Color.Green
    WallNorth.Top = 1
    WallNorth.Left = 1
    WallNorth.SetBounds(x:=1, y:=1, height:=5, width:=750)


    Private Sub PlayScreen_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyValue
        Case Keys.Right
            MoveRight = True
        Case Keys.Left
            MoveLeft = True  'This edits the boolean value of the varibales when the correct key is pressed
        Case Keys.Up
            MoveUp = True
        Case Keys.Down
            MoveDown = True
    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub PlayScreen_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    Select Case e.KeyValue
        Case Keys.Right
            MoveRight = False
        Case Keys.Left
            MoveLeft = False 'This edits the boolean value when the key has been lifted
        Case Keys.Up
            MoveUp = False
        Case Keys.Down
            MoveDown = False
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub MovementTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MovementTimer.Tick
    If MoveRight = True Then
        PlayerShip.Left += 5
    End If
    If MoveLeft = True Then
        PlayerShip.Left -= 5
    End If
    If MoveUp = True Then
        PlayerShip.Top -= 5 ' I use a timer to tick every 10 milliseconds ato check the states of each key, this statement controlls the execution of the direction
    End If
    If MoveDown = True Then
        PlayerShip.Top += 5
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

However when i try to write an if statement to check if they will collide or not i do not get a '.bounds' option. I have seen '.bounds' being needed after the name of the picture box. Instead i have been met with '.setbounds' even though i have set them before.

Is something wrong with my version of visual studio, or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you're using the wrong object. `Bounds` is a property derived from Control: all controls have it.  Btw, you don't need to set Left, Top, Width, Height **AND** call SetBounds(). You can simply use the `Bounds` property and set that: it will call `SetBounds()` for you, also setting `BoundsSpecified.All`. You should show the code that generates and *detects* the collision. Also, where you defined `PlayerShip` and `WallNorth`, since you're not creating the instance here.

Comment: I defined them as picture boxes, ive seen people do the same on youtube etc but it just doesnt work for me, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Not what **Type** of objects, but **where/when** you're creating their instances. There's no `New WallNorth()` or `New PlayerShip()` in this code. Did you create these controls at Desing-Time? Are you actually adding them again to the `Form.Controls` collection? Where's the piece of code that moves them and the code that detects the collision?

Comment: I declared them before any private or publics subs in the class, they have been declared inside the public class of the form